# knockout.js - set a boolean flag within a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

With the following knockout.js code, I'd like to set a flag within an inner loop and then use the flag outside of the loop.  What's the best way to do this?

```
<!-- there is an ASP.NET outer loop here -->

<!-- initialize variable 'myFlag = true' here -->
<div data-bind="foreach: jobs">                             
  <!-- ko if: industry == 'tech' --> 
    <!-- set myFlag to false here -->
    <!-- display job info here -->
  <!-- /ko -->                

  <!-- ko if: myFlag == true -->
    <!-- display 'no jobs for industry' message here -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>   

<!-- end outer ASP.NET outer loop -->
```

Comment: Why not just add a computed observable to each job, when the industry = "tech" make the observable true, otherwise false.

Comment: Well the thing is I'm looping through jobs that have 4 different types of industries, and so when I have no jobs in the "Finance" section, I want to show "There are no jobs for Finance".

Comment: Put a computed observable on the view model which returns the number of jobs where industry = finance. Then you can use a conditional binding like if: jobsInFinance() === 0 instead of your boolean.

Comment: I have a section for each job type, and then a list of jobs within that section for jobs of that job type.  If there are no jobs of that job type, then I'd like to say "no jobs".  Therefore, the flag needs to be a resettable dynamic flag.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the afterRender property of the foreach binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: jobs, afterRender: doSomething }">
```

This will call doSomething for each iteration of jobs.

Comment: This seems like the right direction, but I'm not finding any good examples of how to actually implement it.

Comment: You can find some more info at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html, such as the inputs for the afterRender callback and other foreach callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5e3UL/3/

Comment: This is definitely on the right track -- so should happen when there are no jobs in "real estate" is we should see a message that says "there are no jobs for real estate".  Hence, I think I want to do a length check.

Comment: Yes, in my example I don't know about industries that don't have any jobs. Depending on the structure of the data from the server you may be able to get that from the server. If you can provide more detail about the data coming back from the server I can be more specific.